# Can makeQuicktimeMovie be used for png file?

Tags: python, jython, quicktime, movie, jes

I am using JES, and have my png files ready to makeQuicktimeMovie.
I can't find anywhere, can I use png files?

The JES function as follows:

```
def makeQuicktimeMovie():
  file = pickAFile()
  myMovie = makeMovieFromInitialFile(file)
  writeQuicktime(myMovie, "C:\\myframes\\myMovie.mov", 30)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the [document](http://personal.denison.edu/~bressoud/cs110-f12/Supplements/JESHelp/9_Video_Functions.html):

> **makeMovieFromInitialFile(filename):**
>
> **filename:** string path to the first frame of the movie.
>
> **returns:** a Movie object using the given file as the first frame
>       Takes a filename as input. Returns a Movie object using the given file as the first frame and ***using sequentially named files*** for subsequent frames (i.e. frame001, frame002, etc.)

---

**EDIT :**

It seems that both `writeQuicktime()` and `writeAVI()` work with **`.jpg`s sequences ONLY** (tested under Windows and Linux).