# Saving a movie generated with Jython/JES on local disk

Tags: java, save, jython, movie, jes

I made an autogenerated movie clip using JES (Jython Environment for Students).

I can play it without any problem using `playMovie()`, but I can't figure out how to have it saved physically on disk.

The full script is located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17288511/1715716).

```
...
movie = synthesizeFrameAndCreateMovie("D:\\FOLDER")
print movie
writeQuicktime(movie,"D:\\FOLDER\\movie.mov", 30)             [LINE 35]
#playMovie(movie)
```

I get this error when calling the function `writeQuicktime()`:

```
>>> 
======= Loading Progam =======
Movie, frames: 60
The error was: Index: 0, Size: 0
I wasn't able to do what you wanted.
The error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException has occured
Please check line 35
```

Note : I also tried the function `writeAVI()`, with the exact same result.

This error sounds like a java bug in  Jython/JES library.

I am running JES under Windows 7 and have all the common Quicktime and AVI codex installed as well as the QTjava library in my jre... Any brilliant idea ?

---

***EDIT :***

Also tried the Linux version with same scenario for both QuickTime and AVI...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer is: Do not use `.png`s as input frames, use `.jpg`s instead. See the related topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17290162/1715716). Thanks [Yve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1082944/yve) for the workaround.